# Dynamic allocation not working for global integer pointer

Tags: c++

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int *p;
void fun(int *arr, int n)
{
    p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 1));
    cout << sizeof(p) / sizeof(int) << " " << sizeof(p) << " " << sizeof(int) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    fun(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
4
2 1 4 3
```

Output:

```
2 8 4
```

Expected Output:

```
5 20 4
```

The code returns an incorrect value of the size which is being allocated to the array using malloc. I identified this problem when I used `memset(p, -1, sizeof(p)))`and the array was incorrectly initialized. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The size of a pointer is the size of the *pointer*, not what it points to. You can easily solve this by *not* having manual and explicit dynamic memory handling, and instead use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Especially considering that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is not part of the C++ standard, and is a compiler-specific and non-portable extension.

Comment: And in C++ never use `malloc`. It works for simple types like `int` arrays, but since it *only* allocates memory, if you use it for objects that needs construction that construction won't happen. If you *must* use explicit dynamic allocation (assignment or exercise requirement perhaps) then use `new[]`. Perhaps it's time you invest in [a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read?

Comment: `sizeof(p) / sizeof(int)` makes no sense. `p` isn't an array object, it's simply a pointer. To which your first expression reduces to simply `sizeof (a_pointer)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is what I was wondering because I am used to using `memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));` for arrays and it works perfectly. Thank You.

Comment: Relevant: [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492384/580083).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `p` is a pointer `sizeof(p)` will return 8 (or 4 on 32 bit systems). Because that is the size used by p. The memory size used by the structure p points to is another story